# update empty object, {}, using setState in React functional component

Tags: json, reactjs, setstate

thank you for your attention. I got null when I tried to update the empty object. Any help is appreciated. :)

In React functional component where useState is:

`const [user, setUser] = useState({});`

Initially, the user is an empty object, I tried to update the user with JSON object.

// the new object looks something like this
`{jwt:-----, name:-----, email:-----}`

`setUser(newUser);`

but when I `console.log(user)`, I got null.

// the whole code is below:

```
export default function Test(props) {

  const [user, setUser] = useState({});
  useEffect(() => {
    // when I console.log(userTemp), I got the JSON object as a response as expected
    let userTemp = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('thisUser'))
    
    setUser(userTemp);
    // But, when I tried to log user now (even outside of this method), it gives me null.
  }, []);
```

Comment: If you console user right after `setUser`, it won't show you updated value of user. Try to console log it outside the `useEffect` function

Comment: Hi Ega, I tried this one too, but I still got the null.

Answer (score 1):

```
const [user, setUser] = useState({});
  localStorage.setItem('thisUser','{"name":"John", "age":30, "city":"New York"}')
  useEffect(() => {
    let userTemp = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('thisUser'));
    console.log(userTemp)
    setUser(userTemp)
    console.log('I want to see updated user')
    console.log(user);
  }, [])

  console.log('Its outside useEffect')
  console.log(user);
```

I did exactly same as yours, in `console.log` outside `useEffect` the user state is updated as expected. Any differences?

Answer (score 1):

Actually it's related to when you're setting the `user` to `localStorage`, which you didn't mentioned in your answer. You should set an object to `localStorage` in this way:

```
localStorage.setItem("user", JSON.stringify({ id: 1, name: "biraj" }));
```

And you should get the object from `localStorage` same as bellow:

```
let user = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("user"));
```

Here's the full example how to set and get an object from `localStorage`:

```
import * as React from "react";

localStorage.setItem("user", JSON.stringify({ id: 1, name: "biraj" }));

export default function App() {
  const [user, setUser] = React.useState({});
  React.useEffect(() => {
    let userTemp = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("user"));
    setUser(userTemp);
  }, []);

  return (
    <>
      <h1>{user.id}</h1>
      <h2>{user.name}</h2>
    </>
  );
}
```

[image: Edit restless-haze-dntx6]

Comment: @birajsilwal Your welcome and Please acc.ept it if it solved your problem.